# Problems in installaing Magento in Windows Shared Server using Plesk

Tags: magento, installation

I don´t know how to do. I always have the same error no matter what I do to protect the files. The host (mochahost) don´t give me any support. So I will try if a good soul here could help me.

These are the errors:

Warning: include_once(Mage/Core/functions.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\vhosts\e-interage.com.br\httpdocs\dinossauros\app\Mage.php on line 49

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Mage/Core/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\inetpub\vhosts\e-interage.com.br\httpdocs\dinossauros\app\code\local;C:\inetpub\vhosts\e-interage.com.br\httpdocs\dinossauros\app\code\community;C:\inetpub\vhosts\e-interage.com.br\httpdocs\dinossauros\app\code\core;C:\inetpub\vhosts\e-interage.com.br\httpdocs\dinossauros\lib;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\Pear;./includes;./pear;./;') in C:\inetpub\vhosts\e-interage.com.br\httpdocs\dinossauros\app\Mage.php on line 49

Warning: Varien_Autoload::include(Mage\Core\Model\App.php) [varien-autoload.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\vhosts\e-interage.com.br\httpdocs\dinossauros\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93

Warning: Varien_Autoload::include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Mage\Core\Model\App.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\inetpub\vhosts\e-interage.com.br\httpdocs\dinossauros\app\code\local;C:\inetpub\vhosts\e-interage.com.br\httpdocs\dinossauros\app\code\community;C:\inetpub\vhosts\e-interage.com.br\httpdocs\dinossauros\app\code\core;C:\inetpub\vhosts\e-interage.com.br\httpdocs\dinossauros\lib;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\Pear;./includes;./pear;./;') in C:\inetpub\vhosts\e-interage.com.br\httpdocs\dinossauros\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_App' not found in C:\inetpub\vhosts\e-interage.com.br\httpdocs\dinossauros\app\Mage.php on line 620

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your question - you are 'installing Magento in Windows Shared Server using Plesk.'

You are using Windows shared hosting for an application developed for a linux box, preferably one with lots of resources.

Even if you get this working you will be spending your time adapting the software to your setup, not developing your shop.

How much do you value your time?

Is it more than your (shared) computer's time?

If so, get the right hosting, which at a minimum is virtual server, linux flavour. The installation instructions will work for you. Same with any other problems you have with your build - all the instructions and forum tips are for linux, i.e. with the path separators going '/' and not Microsoft backwards-'\'.

Comment: You must be right. The problem is that I have been successful in a similar attempt in another provider with the same characteristics.

Comment: My current provider is MochaHost and they refuse to support me at this issue.

Comment: Good riddance to them! You are not tied to the hip with them and you are best advised to get a VM that your clients pay for and you make money from. Chicken and egg - maybe, but with your own hosting environment you don't have to rely on a support desk.